# How to format my aws lambda function results into incremented numbers

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to get an output of my lambda function to output like this. Every entry that matches the query starts with a zero and then i+

[image: Good Output]

**My Code**

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode = 0;

  const params = {
    TableName: "userEducation",

  };

  try {
    const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
    statusCode = 200;
  } catch(err) {
    responseBody = `Unable to get products: ${err}`;
    statusCode = 403;
  }

  const response = {

    body: responseBody
  };

  return response;
};
```

**My Wrong Output**

[image: Wrong Output]

Comment: you need to json decode the content of `body`

Comment: any other keywords to help me on my search ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decoded the 'responseBody' with JSON.parse before returning it.

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode = 0;

  const params = {
    TableName: "userEducation",

  };

  try {
    const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
  } catch(err) {
    responseBody = `Unable to get edu: ${err}`;
  }
  
  const obj = JSON.parse(responseBody)
  

  return obj;
};
```